# SignalR: worker process is limited to 10 concurrent requests

Tags: iis, azure, signalr

I've deployed a SignalR-based app onto my on-premises server, and it is crashing when there are more than ten concurrent users.

The long-running requests for the worker process associated with my app pool all have URLs of the form `/signalr/reconnect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=...`.

As soon as more than ten users connect, the limit of ten concurrent requests is breached and the application hangs.

Do I need to change any IIS settings to allow SignalR to scale in this instance?  If I'm deploying to Azure, how would I configure the settings to take account of this?

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate, Service Pack 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Workstation OSes (Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, etc) have a [limit of at most 10 concurrent connections](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2012/11/13/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit.aspx) in IIS.  These OSes are not intended for use as a server (and I think the EULA prohibits it, as I recall).  The concurrent connection limit is one way that Microsoft enforces the "not a server" restriction.

Windows Server OSes (Server 2008 R2, Server 2012, etc) do not have this restriction, and so you won't have this problem when you deploy you application to a production server.  Windows Azure is fine also (it is Windows Server behind the scenes).

Comment: Patching tcpip.sys is no longer a viable workaround as IIS now has these limits embedded in it as well.  IIS now queues any requests beyond the limit instead of just rejecting them at the OS level.