# IIS 10 hangs after few connections via SignalR

Tags: signalr, iis-10

I ran into problems developing an application (.Net Framework 4.7+) using SignalR (v. 2.2). My IIS (v. 10 on Windows 10 HOME) is hanging after 2 established connections. It hangs completely, so no other site, hosted there, is no longer available.

I trieid to reproduce it on sample project (SignalR Chat). I downloaded it from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Getting-Started-with-c366b2f3). Hosted it in IIS. IIS hangs after 2 established connections (2 tab opened, on third tab page opens from cache, but message isn't posted, if force refresh with CTRL+F5, then page not loading at all). I updated the sapmple project to the latest versions of SignalR and OWIN. Same result.

Ok. I took a clean system (Windows 10 PRO), installed IIS there, hosted sample project there. Instead of 2 connections it hangs after 9 websocket connections. I tried to change the transport to LongPolling, and server hangs after 6 connections. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms) is noted that on client OS (like WIndows 10) there is a limitation to 10 simultaneous connections. But not 2. Using IISExpress there are no such restrictions.

Checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27019004/signalr-makes-iis-hang-after-rebuild) question. But there is no CPU usage at all. I tried all the solutions proposed [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3414). No result.

2 simultaneous is extremely low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using a non server version of IIS. Deploy it to a server and it'll be fine.

Similar questions and answers: [SignalR: worker process is limited to 10 concurrent requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380205/signalr-worker-process-is-limited-to-10-concurrent-requests)

Comment: I know about this. Problem is in limitation to 2 connection instead of 10

Comment: You're assuming a single tab using SignalR uses just a single TCP connection (which it never will). As creating new connections is slow, it's not unusual for a browser to hold onto multiple TCP connections... I'm guessing you really don't want to buy Windows Server, but the official answer will just be *put it on Windows Server and you'll be fine*